# Tastypie: implement resouce DELETE on custom url

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I want to implement the deletion of a resource using a custom url. So, instead of allowing the DELETE on the default resource Tastypie url, I've defined a new one. The delete works but I'm still getting an error because I'm sure I'm missing something in my code. The function performing the delete is `cancel_ride_request`.

```
class DemandResource(ModelResource):
"""
Handles ride requests resources. In particular:
    - Offers information about the logged user's ride requests
    - Allows new ride requests creation
"""

user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'passenger')
origin = fields.ForeignKey(NodeResource, 'origin', full=True)
destination = fields.ForeignKey(NodeResource, 'destination', full=True)

potential_drivers = fields.ListField(readonly=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = api.models.Demand.objects.all()
    resource_name = _Helpers.demand_resource_name
    list_allowed_methods = ['get']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch']
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()

def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/register%s" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('register_ride_request'), name="api_ask_ride"),
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>.*?)/cancel%s" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('cancel_ride_request'), name="api_cancel_ride_request"),
            ]

@classmethod
def dehydrate_potential_drivers(cls, bundle):
    return _Helpers.serialise_passengerships_passenger(bundle.obj.passengership_set.select_related().all())

def hydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['user'] = bundle.request.user

    #extract orign and destination ID
    bundle.data['origin'] = api.models.Node.objects.get(id=bundle.data['origin']['id'])
    bundle.data['destination'] = api.models.Node.objects.get(id=bundle.data['destination']['id'])

    bundle.data['arrival_time'] = datetime.strptime(bundle.data['arrival_time'], _Helpers.date_time_format)
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels') #TODO get the user time zone
    bundle.data['arrival_time'] = tz.localize(bundle.data['arrival_time'])
    bundle.data['arrival_time_tolerance_early'] = timedelta(minutes=int(bundle.data['arrival_time_tolerance_early']))
    bundle.data['arrival_time_tolerance_late'] = timedelta(minutes=int(bundle.data['arrival_time_tolerance_late']))

    return bundle

def register_ride_request(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, ['post', ])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    bundle = self.build_bundle(data=data, request=request)
    bundle = self.hydrate(bundle)
    demand = api.models.Demand(passenger=bundle.request.user,
                               origin=bundle.data['origin'],
                               destination=bundle.data['destination'],
                               arrival_time=bundle.data['arrival_time'],
                               arrival_time_tolerance_early=bundle.data['arrival_time_tolerance_early'],
                               arrival_time_tolerance_late=bundle.data['arrival_time_tolerance_late'])
    demand.save()
    return HttpResponse(status=201)

"""
Handling demand deletion, making sure the request type is a DELETE and the user is authenticated
"""
def cancel_ride_request(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, ['delete', ])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    return api.models.Demand.objects.filter(pk=kwargs['pk']).delete()

"""
Makes sure that only the owner of a demand is able to delete it
"""
def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    return bundle.obj.passenger == bundle.request.user
```

I also think the way I've implemented the resource creation with the function `register_ride_request` is not optimal. It does work but it's weird that I have to manually return the `HTTPResponse` code. Isn't there a better way to do it?
Thanks and sorry for the two questions in one post, but I feel they are related.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a solution, even tho I'm not sure it's the best approach, so I'm more than happy if somebody wants to comment it. I've implemented a custom Authorization class which has, among the others, the following methods:

```
class UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization(Authorization)

    def delete_detail(self, bundle):
        return self.request_is_from_owner(bundle)

    def request_is_from_owner(self, bundle):
        if hasattr(bundle.obj, "passenger"):
            return bundle.obj.passenger.pk == bundle.request.user.member.pk 
        elif hasattr(bundle.obj, "driver"):
            return bundle.obj.driver == bundle.request.user.member
        return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user.member
```

This class is used to ensure that only the owner of the object is allowed to delete it.
Then, in my `DemandResource` class, since the deletion of the resouce occurs at a custom URL, I've overwritten the `obj_delete` method. Below I show the code for the custom URL, the function answering the request and the overwritten `obj_delete` method, which uses the custom Authorization class to make sure the request is authorized (everything is in the class `DemandResource`):

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/register%s" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('register_ride_request'), name="api_ask_ride"),
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>.*?)/cancel%s" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('cancel_ride_request'), name="api_cancel_ride_request"),
            ]

def cancel_ride_request(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Handling demand deletion, making sure the request type is a DELETE and the user is authenticated
    :param request: the HTTP request data
    """
    self.method_check(request, ['delete', ])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    # call the delete, deleting the obj from the database
    try:
        # get an instance of the bundle.obj that will be deleted
        obj = api.models.Demand.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound("The object does not exist.")
    bundle = Bundle(request=request, obj=obj)
    if self._meta.authorization.delete_detail(bundle):
        try:
            print "Entered"
            self.obj_delete(bundle, **kwargs)
            return http.HttpNoContent()
        except NotFound:
            return http.HttpNotFound()
    else: return HttpResponse(status=401) #unauthorized

def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    try:
        # get an instance of the bundle.obj that will be deleted
        api.models.Demand.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']).delete()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound("The object does not exist.")
```